# Convert NSNumber to NSTimeInterval in Swift

Tags: swift, casting, ios8, nsnumber, nstimeinterval

I'm stuck with some sort of casting in Swift as I am very new to Swift.

Here is my code:

```
 if let matchDateTime = item["matchDate"].number {
     _matchDateTime=matchDateTime
 }

 println(_matchDateTime)                      
 let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:_matchDateTime)
```

but its giving me the error:

```
Extra argument timeSinceInterval1970 in call
```

I don't know whats that error, may be convert `NSNumber` to `NSTimeInterval` but how? No idea.

Anyone who can help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to click the check mark to accept one of the correct answers you've been given. Up-voting is entirely optional, but by asking a question you are expected to accept the best answer given if it answers the question. Failing to accept a correct answer is considered rude on SO.

Comment: You need to accept one of the answer you have been given, or explain how they don't solve your problem. Failure to accept a correct answer is considered very bad form on SO.

Answer (score 32):

`NSTimeInterval` is just a typedaliased `Double`.

Therefore casting from NSNumber to NSTimeInterval:

```
let myDouble = NSNumber(double: 1.0)
let myTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(myDouble.doubleValue)
```

Edit:
And the reverse is true.

```
let myTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(1.0)
let myDouble = NSNumber(double: myTimeInterval)
```

Edit 2:
As @DuncanC points out in the comments below, you can cast directly in the method call:

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(_matchDateTime))
```

Comment: Swift is nicer about casting between NSNumber and scalar number types than Objective-C is, so you can also use the syntax `Double(myDouble)` or `NSTimeInterval(myDouble)` where `myDouble` is an NSNumber like in your answer.

Comment: That's great that Swift handles that in a nicer way. I still prefer the above method as it is cleaner (IMO) and less likely to break with a new version of Swift (as it uses the established Cocoa API for NSNumber).

Comment: Fair enough. I prefer the Swift style when working in Swift. Personal taste, I suppose. (And I think that changes to a core feature like type casting are exceedingly unlikely. That part of the language is well defined.)

Answer (score 5):

Try casting your NSNumber to a Double. This code works in a playground:

```
let aNumber: NSNumber = 1234567.89
let aDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: Double(aNumber))
```

Comment: You should accept either my or Blake's answer. Both solve your problem. Pick the one you're more comfortable with.